# calculating adjacent xor

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, xor

Input is a boolean array `a_0,i` with at most 1000,000 elements.

each time the new array is made by `xor` of adjacent(cyclic) elements in previous array:

```
a_t,i = a_t-1,i ^ a_t-1,(i+1)%n     // n is size of input
```

The p-th array(a_p,i) is wanted.(p <= 1000,000,000).

According to high bound on `p` I think maybe there is a structure of arrays or maybe the array can be calculated in `O(lg(p) * n)`.

Comment: What is your question for the SO audience?

Comment: Also, you're using big-O notation, which implies growth to infinity.  This conflicts with the fact that you've specified constraints on `n` and `p`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: specifying constraints is a hint, it shows there is a better solution than O(n*p)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If t is a power of two (t=2<sup>k</sup>),

```
a_t,i = a_0,i ^ a_0,(i+t)%n
```

Also, if t is a sum of two components, and one of them is a power of two (t = v + w, w=2<sup>m</sup>),

```
a_t,i = a_v,i ^ a_v,(i+w)%n
```

This allows using binary representation of p to recursively compute the resulting array. The complexity is as requested: O(lg(p) * n):

```
shift = 1;
while (p != 0)
{
  if (p&1)
    a ^= a.rotate(shift);
  shift *= 2
  p /= 2
}
```

Comment: You said if `t = v + w` and v and w are powers of two then `a_t,i = a_v,i ^ a_w,i` but in Right-to-left binary method method v and w are not necessarily powers of two.

Comment: @a-z, right, this problem is even simpler than modular exponentiation, because we can directly compute an array for any power of two.

Comment: You mean the second formula works for any `v` and `w`?(not just powers of two)

Comment: Your first formula seems correct, but I think the second one isn't.

Comment: @a-z, the second formula is now just an extension of the first one, and it immediately solves the problem.

Comment: According to the formula for n = 5, a_3,0 must be a_0,0^a_0,1^a_0,2 but it's equal to a_0,0^a_0,1^a_0,2^a_0,3.

Comment: @a-z, I think, now it is correct.